# asp.net getting value from dynamiccontrol entity database field inside formview

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, webforms, formview

I have the following code in aspx:

```
<asp.DynamicControl ID="ArticleName" runat="server" DataField="Name" Mode="Edit"/>
```

How in code behind i get the value of DataField in this DynamicControl (for example DataField Value = "Ball" ) ?

I have tried this but doesn't work:

```
protected void FormView1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DynamicControl myControl = (DynamicControl)FormView1.FindControl("ArticleName");
    if (myControl != null)
    {
        // Now What ???
        //string st = myControl.< I need help here >
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your markup code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it :

```
protected void FormView1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ctrl = FormView1.FindFieldTemplate("name") as IBindableControl;
    OrderedDictionary entityValues = new OrderedDictionary();

    entityValues.Add("name", null); // I have to initialize before
    ctrl.ExtractValues(entityValues); // Get values from FormView in this case only the article name field

    string myVal = entityValues["name"].ToString(); // This is what i want
}
```

Thanks,
Filipe Pinto

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
string value = myControl.DataField;
```

Comment: Hello Christos. Your answer returns "Name" (DataField="Name"). I want the value linked to database field "Name". I have this FormView linked to a datasource using Entity Framework. In the FormView i have the information from Article Name (and other fields, like price, color, etc), but i need the value or the article name on code behind.